# Error handling with Q promise

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise, q

So, I have the following code

```
Q.fcall(foo(input))
.then(
  () ->
    # do stuff
)
.fail(
  # this never gets called
)

foo = (input) ->
  throw new Error('catch me!')
```

And I get the following error: `Uncaught Error: catch me!`. Per the [docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) The `.fail` call should catch any errors thrown by `foo` - Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the code of `foo`?

Comment: For the sake of the example foo is just a method throwing an error when invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `Q.fcall(foo, input)`

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe I missed that in the docs! :-)